# not understanding repeating-linear-gradient color stops

Tags: css

I am a newbie learning web dev. I am trying to learn from MDN Docs. They have made available tutorials, so its easy to follow. But their material on `repeating-linear-gradient` is confusing to me. They have following code given on their [site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/repeating-linear-gradient#syntax). I have added `div` here so that gradient can be seen in the code snippet.

```css
div {
  height: 600px;
  width: 600px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(to right, red 0%, green 10%, red 20%);

}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

The explanation given for this is

`A gradient repeating five times, going from the left to right, starting red, turning green, and back to red`

I understand from left to right. But why is this repeated five times? I also have trouble understanding the stops given. Does `red` start at 0% or stop at 0% ? MDN docs are confusing in this regard. Can anybody explain ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets take the `repeating linear-gradient` syntax from start to end.

`to right` defines the direction of the gradient. In this case from left to right.
`red 0%` means that it should start with red at 0% of the distance.
`green 10%` will let green be at the 10% distance while the colors will merge (gradient effect).
`red 20%` is the last value of the syntax and it means that it should end at 20% with red.

[image]

```
0%     pure red
1-4%   more red than green (decreasing)
5%     equally red and green
6-9%   more green than red (increasing)
10%    pure green
11-14% more green than red (decreasing)
15%    equally red and green
16-19% more red than green (increasing)
20%    solid red
21-24% more red than green (decreasing>
25%    equally green and red
... keeps repeating
```

After that it will self-repeat. `100% / 20% = 5` and that's why it repeats itself 5 times.
If we add a new Value such as `blue 50%` then it takes 50% of the distance and can only repeat twice:

```css
div {
  height: 600px;
  width: 600px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(to right, red 0%, green 10%, red 20%, blue 50%);

}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: so does `green` start at 10% or end at 10% ? In the image posted by you, I see green before and after 10% boundary.

Comment: no green is solid or pure at 10%. I added further explanation of it under the pciture.